# Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\example.exe" because it was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I click **start** at Visual Studio direct show my that error

> Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\example.exe" because it was not found

I tried :

- prebuild event
- close and open Visual Studio
- kill the process at task manager

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder in your project directory and then try building your project.

Comment: @RahulSharma what did you mean .vs ? there is no any folder wish .vs

Comment: @It is a hidden folder which resides where your .sln file is.

Comment: @RahulSharma there is no any file , have a look my screen shoot

https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501942138685

Comment: I cannot see any image from the link that you posted. And it is not a file but a hidden folder called `.vs` and it resides where your `.sln` file is. Try deleting that folder and then rebuilding your project again.

Comment: Did you get this resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

try to clean and build the solution.. or rebuild the solution. files inside debug will be removed on clean and build to re-generate those files.